# Photoelectric effect of carbon

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Why does Carbon show photoelectric effect being a non metal and how high is the threshold frequency for emitting photoelectron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The photoelectric effect is essentially the expulsion of an electron bound to an atom by the incoming photon. The requirement is that the energy of the photon exceeds (or equals) the binding energy of the electron that is expelled. This is essentially the ionisation energy of the material in question, which in the case of carbon under normal conditions is 11.26 eV according to Wikipedia. I make this 2.72 x 10$^{15}$ Hz as a photon frequency.

There is no requirement that the material in question is metallic.

Comment: In the link below we see the 4.81eV for carbon

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Tables/photoelec.html#c1